# vba remove duplicates rows based on higher corresponding values

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have the following lists.

```
z   LL  ST
1   40  160
2   40  51
3   35  77
4   39  100
5   34  78
6   39  89
7   33  49
8   31  80
9   35  101
10  38  57
11  32  52
12  40  84
13  37  102
14  40  135
15  31  55
16  34  59
17  40  115
18  35  62
19  40  168
20  39  68
21  37  67
```

I am wanting to remove the rows with duplicate values of LL but keep the one with the greatest ST value.  For example, all LL = 40 except the one with the corresponding ST = 160 would be removed.  I have found ways to remove duplicates, but I can't find a code more specific to my issue.  Thanks for assisting.

Comment: Sort on ST Descending, then use Remove Duplicates under the Data tab based on column LL.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to use VBA code.  this is a sample of a much bigger project.  But I will see if I can use this to get the code off of running it as a macro.

Comment: You can easily incorporate the steps above in vba.  Use the recorder do it manually and then incorporate it in.  It will be quicker than looping and comparing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Guess I was trying to make it more difficult than I needed to .  lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the code, here it is.  Thanks again for the assistance.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("A2:M23").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scratchsheet (2)").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scratchsheet (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        Cells(3, 11), Cells(23, 11)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scratchsheet (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        Cells(3, 12), Cells(23, 12)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scratchsheet (2)").Sort
        .SetRange Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(23, 12))
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(23, 12)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=11, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```